# substituting black treacle/molasses for brown sugar

Tags: baking, substitutions, cake, brown-sugar

I would like to replace some of the brown sugar in a dark fruit cake recipe with black treacle (similar to molasses I believe), as I like the rich taste and think it will add to the moistness of the cake. But I don't know what quantity to use instead. The recipe calls for 200 grams of brown sugar, so I was thinking of replacing half of it maybe? I've seen a different recipe for a similar size cake that uses 150 g brown sugar and 1 tablespoon of black treacle, so perhaps that would be a better idea? I'm using the dark soft muscovado sugar as the recipe suggests, but I really want a dark, rich, moist, almost sticky cake, almost more like a Christmas pudding in texture. Hope someone can help :-)

Answer (score 2):

A standard substitute for brown sugar is to take 1 Cup = 200 g of white granulated sugar, and mix-in 1 tablespoon of molasses/treacle.  There's a lot of flavor in that tablespoon.

My own recommendation would be to either supplement your full 200 g of brown sugar with a tablespoon of treacle or consider using 200 g of granulated sugar and mix-in 2 tablespoons of treacle.

Since you are planning to use dark soft muscovado sugar (which is already flavorful) in your recipe, I think supplementing the full 200 g amount with 1 tablespoon of treacle would give your cake a terrific taste.

Comment: Thanks so much, really helpful replies :-) My first time on this site, I'm really impressed with how quickly I got answers.

Comment: Oh, I missed the part about her using muscovado.

Answer (score 0):

The key to what you're trying to do is to not *replace* brown sugar, but to make it. Mix white sugar and treacle (or molasses, same thing) in a food processor. Start with about a tablespoon of treacle to 1 cup (200 grams) of white, granulated sugar. You might end wanting two or three times that amount of treacle. Just gauge it by color. That's how brown sugar is made.

**EDIT** I missed that you're using muscovado, that's fine. I lowballed it to recommend 1 TBS of treacle, so that's still in the ballpark.